# How to get the <input value of a form in JavaScript that doesn't have an id?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm trying to extract the values of a form in the HTML code. The form is written in Java script.

this is the function I am using currently, it uses the form id from  :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="frm1">
            <tr>
             <td nowrap="nowrap">
              <label>Number of Panels</label>
             </td>
             <td>
              <input class="display" type="text" size="8" readonly="readonly" value="20"/>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <br>

Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
</form> 

<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of this after clicking the "Try it" button will give:
20
Duck

My Question is, the actual script doesn't have a form id in it, as so:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
            <tr>
             <td nowrap="nowrap">
              <label>Number of Panels</label>
             </td>
             <td>
              <input class="display" type="text" size="8" readonly="readonly" value="20"/>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <br>

Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
</form> 

<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the value of this form that doesn't have an Id?

Cheers!

Comment: You can try `document.getElementsByTagName("form")`

Comment: Steven V, it's not a duplicate :)

My form itself doesn't have an id="xxx" not the <input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern browsers (and IE8), you can use `document.querySelector` to use any [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) to find an element.

In your case, for instance, you could use

```
var x = document.querySelector('[action="form_action.asp"]');
```

...to look it up by the value of its `action` attribute. The rest of your function doesn't change.

`querySelector` finds the *first* matching element. If you want a list of *all* matching elements, you can use `querySelectorAll`. In your case, for instance, if you want a list of the `input` elements inside the form, you could do this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[action="form_action.asp"] input');
```

e.g.:

```
function myFunction() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[action="form_action.asp"] input');
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length ;i++) {
        text += elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I didn't have anything but <table> and action="form_action.asp" doesn't exist. Cause that'actually what I'm dealing with.

Comment: @AhmadK: Then why did your question have the `action`? Anyway, the main point is: Anything CSS selector you can come up with to match the form or the elements within it will let you get them via `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
var x = document.forms[0];
```

And for inputs, you can just do `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index]`

Comment: Not working, any other suggestions?